# Find longest word + length from string input

Tags: c, arrays, eof, string-length

This is only my third or fourth program so bear with me:
I have to write a program that reads string input until EOF and then prints the longest word + its length. I'm not supposed to use strlen(). This is the skeleton code that's been provided -

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const int max_word_len = 50;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    int c = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int longest;
    char current[max_word_len];
    char longest[max_word_len];

    while(... != EOF && i < max_word_len-1){

    }
}
```

I then have to make use of this:

```
void copy(char src[], char dst[], int count);
```

I've no clue how to proceed so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please expand on `find the longest word` . An example would really help. Also, doesn't matter if you are new, please show what you have already tried. Doesn't matter how good/bad the code is :)

Comment: It's harder to use this pre-made template crap than writing this program from scratch... so I'd advise to do the latter.

Comment: Every time you detect a space save the word in a buffer. When you detect the next word check whether it is longer, if it is replace the word in the buffer. When you're out of the loop the buffer will contain the longest word.